# c++ linux send uninitialised sockets memory

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, memory

I'm new and I'm using debian 10 x64. Why is error in the line with SEND? Someone can sugest me how to fix that problem?

**send(socket, (char*)m_MsgBuf+sendBytes, std::min(m_MsgSize-sendBytes+2, 1000),**

I got that ERROR LOG:

```
==24819== Thread 3:
==24819== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==24819==    at 0x51442B4: __libc_send (send.c:28)
==24819==    by 0x51442B4: send (send.c:23)
==24819==    by 0x1FCFC9: NetworkMessage::WriteToSocket(int) (networkmessage.cpp:117)
==24819==    by 0x231624: Protocol76::flushOutputBuffer() (protocol76.cpp:3574)
==24819==    by 0x22ECF4: Protocol76::sendThingAppear(Thing const*) (protocol76.cpp:3039)
==24819==    by 0x214DE1: Player::onThingAppear(Thing const*) (player.cpp:2165)
==24819==    by 0x1829D0: Game::sendAddThing(Player*, Position const&, Thing const*) (game.cpp:7005)
==24819==    by 0x16789F: Game::placeCreature(Position&, Creature*, int*) (game.cpp:1260)
==24819==    by 0x223995: Protocol76::ConnectPlayer(int*) (protocol76.cpp:66)
==24819==    by 0x208C43: ConnectionHandler(void*) (otserv.cpp:575)
==24819==    by 0x5139F26: start_thread (pthread_create.c:479)
==24819==    by 0x55F12AE: clone (clone.S:95)
==24819==  Address 0x111137f1 is 289 bytes inside a block of size 16,912 alloc'd
==24819==    at 0x4836DEF: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:344)
==24819==    by 0x2086ED: ConnectionHandler(void*) (otserv.cpp:510)
==24819==    by 0x5139F26: start_thread (pthread_create.c:479)
==24819==    by 0x55F12AE: clone (clone.S:95)
==24819==
```

CODE:

```
bool NetworkMessage::WriteToSocket(SOCKET socket)
{
    if (m_MsgSize == 0)
        return true;

    m_MsgBuf[0] = (unsigned char)(m_MsgSize);
    m_MsgBuf[1] = (unsigned char)(m_MsgSize >> 8);

    bool ret = true;
    int32_t sendBytes = 0;
    int32_t flags = 0;
    int32_t retry = 0;

    flags = MSG_DONTWAIT; // 2 ?

    do
    {
        int32_t b = send(socket, (char*)m_MsgBuf+sendBytes, std::min(m_MsgSize-sendBytes+2, 1000), flags);

        if(b <= 0)
        {   
            int32_t errnum;

            if(errnum == EWOULDBLOCK) 
            {
                b = 0;
                OTSYS_SLEEP(10);
                retry++;

                if(retry == 10) 
                {
                    ret = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ret = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        sendBytes += b;
    }while(sendBytes < m_MsgSize+2);

    return ret;
}


==930== Thread 3:
==930== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==930==    at 0x1FCFE7: NetworkMessage::WriteToSocket(int) (networkmessage.cpp:106)
==930==    by 0x208340: ConnectionHandler(void*) (otserv.cpp:427)
==930==    by 0x5139F26: start_thread (pthread_create.c:479)
==930==    by 0x55F12AE: clone (clone.S:95)
==930==
==930== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==930==    at 0x51442B4: __libc_send (send.c:28)
==930==    by 0x51442B4: send (send.c:23)
==930==    by 0x1FCFD9: NetworkMessage::WriteToSocket(int) (networkmessage.cpp:100)
==930==    by 0x231650: Protocol76::flushOutputBuffer() (protocol76.cpp:3574)
==930==    by 0x22ED20: Protocol76::sendThingAppear(Thing const*) (protocol76.cpp:3039)
==930==    by 0x214E0D: Player::onThingAppear(Thing const*) (player.cpp:2165)
==930==    by 0x1829D0: Game::sendAddThing(Player*, Position const&, Thing const*) (game.cpp:7005)
==930==    by 0x16789F: Game::placeCreature(Position&, Creature*, int*) (game.cpp:1260)
==930==    by 0x2239C1: Protocol76::ConnectPlayer(int*) (protocol76.cpp:66)
==930==    by 0x208C6F: ConnectionHandler(void*) (otserv.cpp:575)
==930==    by 0x5139F26: start_thread (pthread_create.c:479)
==930==    by 0x55F12AE: clone (clone.S:95)
==930==  Address 0x111198d1 is 289 bytes inside a block of size 16,912 alloc'd
==930==    at 0x4836DEF: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:344)
==930==    by 0x208719: ConnectionHandler(void*) (otserv.cpp:510)
==930==    by 0x5139F26: start_thread (pthread_create.c:479)
==930==    by 0x55F12AE: clone (clone.S:95)
==930==
==930== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==930==    at 0x1FCFE7: NetworkMessage::WriteToSocket(int) (networkmessage.cpp:106)
==930==    by 0x231650: Protocol76::flushOutputBuffer() (protocol76.cpp:3574)
==930==    by 0x22ED20: Protocol76::sendThingAppear(Thing const*) (protocol76.cpp:3039)
==930==    by 0x214E0D: Player::onThingAppear(Thing const*) (player.cpp:2165)
==930==    by 0x1829D0: Game::sendAddThing(Player*, Position const&, Thing const*) (game.cpp:7005)
==930==    by 0x16789F: Game::placeCreature(Position&, Creature*, int*) (game.cpp:1260)
==930==    by 0x2239C1: Protocol76::ConnectPlayer(int*) (protocol76.cpp:66)
==930==    by 0x208C6F: ConnectionHandler(void*) (otserv.cpp:575)
==930==    by 0x5139F26: start_thread (pthread_create.c:479)
==930==    by 0x55F12AE: clone (clone.S:95)
==930== Thread 2:
==930== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==930==    at 0x1FCFE7: NetworkMessage::WriteToSocket(int) (networkmessage.cpp:106)
==930==    by 0x231650: Protocol76::flushOutputBuffer() (protocol76.cpp:3574)
==930==    by 0x214089: Player::flushMsg() (player.cpp:1867)
==930==    by 0x182338: Game::flushSendBuffers() (game.cpp:6879)
==930==    by 0x17AAB2: Game::checkCreature(unsigned int) (game.cpp:5461)
==930==    by 0x1A4B67: std::mem_fun1_t<void, Game, unsigned int>::operator()(Game*, unsigned int) const (stl_function.h:1284)
==930==    by 0x1A1668: std::binder2nd<std::mem_fun1_t<void, Game, unsigned int> >::operator()(Game* const&)const (binders.h:158)
==930==    by 0x19BCCD: boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<std::binder2nd<std::mem_fun1_t<void, Game, unsigned int>>,void, Game*>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, Game*) (function_template.hpp:159)
==930==    by 0x23810D: boost::function1<void, Game*>::operator()(Game*) const (function_template.hpp:768)
==930==    by 0x237FBC: TSchedulerTask::operator()(Game*) (scheduler.h:63)
==930==    by 0x166D2B: Game::eventThread(void*) (game.cpp:1045)
==930==    by 0x5139F26: start_thread (pthread_create.c:479)
==930==
==930== Thread 3:
==930== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==930==    at 0x51442B4: __libc_send (send.c:28)
==930==    by 0x51442B4: send (send.c:23)
==930==    by 0x1FCFD9: NetworkMessage::WriteToSocket(int) (networkmessage.cpp:100)
==930==    by 0x231650: Protocol76::flushOutputBuffer() (protocol76.cpp:3574)
==930==    by 0x214089: Player::flushMsg() (player.cpp:1867)
==930==    by 0x182338: Game::flushSendBuffers() (game.cpp:6879)
==930==    by 0x224573: Protocol76::parsePacket(NetworkMessage&) (protocol76.cpp:405)
==930==    by 0x223A3F: Protocol76::ReceiveLoop() (protocol76.cpp:86)
==930==    by 0x208E70: ConnectionHandler(void*) (otserv.cpp:611)
==930==    by 0x5139F26: start_thread (pthread_create.c:479)
==930==    by 0x55F12AE: clone (clone.S:95)
==930==  Address 0x11119f5f is 1,967 bytes inside a block of size 16,912 alloc'd
==930==    at 0x4836DEF: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:344)
==930==    by 0x208719: ConnectionHandler(void*) (otserv.cpp:510)
==930==    by 0x5139F26: start_thread (pthread_create.c:479)
==930==    by 0x55F12AE: clone (clone.S:95)
==930==
```

I use code like this:

```
bool NetworkMessage::WriteToSocket(SOCKET socket)
{
    if (m_MsgSize == 0)
        return true;

    m_MsgBuf[0] = (unsigned char)(m_MsgSize);
    m_MsgBuf[1] = (unsigned char)(m_MsgSize >> 8);

    bool ret = true;
    int32_t sendBytes = 0;
    int32_t flags = 0;
    int32_t retry = 0;

    flags = MSG_DONTWAIT; // 2 ?


    while (sendBytes != m_MsgSize) 
    { /* != rather than < */
        int32_t b = send(socket, (char*)m_MsgBuf+sendBytes, std::min(m_MsgSize-sendBytes+2, 1000), flags);

        if(b <= 0)
        {   
            int32_t errnum;

            if(errnum == EWOULDBLOCK) 
            {
                b = 0;
                OTSYS_SLEEP(10);
                retry++;

                if(retry == 10) 
                {
                    ret = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ret = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        sendBytes += b;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

> **EDIT**

the last time when i had similar error I needed to use that code and now everything is working: `sigemptyset(&sigh.sa_mask);` OR `memset(&sigh, 0, sizeof(sigh));` here i found all msgBuf and msg Size in my project files. Do U see something intresting here? **m_MsgBuf** [wklejto.pl/828244](http://wklejto.pl/828244) **m_MsgSize** [wklejto.pl/828245](http://wklejto.pl/828245)

> **EDIT**

so I did this, in file ***NetworkMessage.cpp*** I have added under AddString/AddU32/AddU16/AddByte this:

```
#ifdef CHECKVAL
    checkval(m_MsgBuf+m_ReadPos, stringlen);
#endif
```

on the top this file I have added:

```
#include "player.h"

#ifdef CHECKVAL
    extern int checkval(unsigned char * buff, int len);
#endif
```

and to the end added this code to ***player.cpp***

```
#ifdef CHECKVAL
int checkval(unsigned char * buff, int len)
{
   int r = 0;

   buff -= len;
   while (len--)
     r += *buff++;
   return r;
}
#endif
```

and also I have changed `char` to `unsigned char` - bcs I got error `invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘char*’`

to END I added to compilator this `-DCHECKVAL`

after that I see same error

```
==15290== Thread 3:
==15290== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==15290==    at 0x51442B4: __libc_send (send.c:28)
==15290==    by 0x51442B4: send (send.c:23)
==15290==    by 0x1FCFDC: NetworkMessage::WriteToSocket(int) (networkmessage.cpp:105)
==15290==    by 0x231728: Protocol76::flushOutputBuffer() (protocol76.cpp:3574)
==15290==    by 0x22EDF8: Protocol76::sendThingAppear(Thing const*) (protocol76. cpp:3039)
==15290==    by 0x214E99: Player::onThingAppear(Thing const*) (player.cpp:2165)
==15290==    by 0x1829D0: Game::sendAddThing(Player*, Position const&, Thing const*) (game.cpp:7005)
==15290==    by 0x16789F: Game::placeCreature(Position&, Creature*, int*) (game.cpp:1260)
==15290==    by 0x223A99: Protocol76::ConnectPlayer(int*) (protocol76.cpp:66)
==15290==    by 0x208CFB: ConnectionHandler(void*) (otserv.cpp:575)
==15290==    by 0x5139F26: start_thread (pthread_create.c:479)
==15290==    by 0x55F12AE: clone (clone.S:95)
==15290==  Address 0x11116331 is 289 bytes inside a block of size 16,912 alloc'd
==15290==    at 0x4836DEF: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:344)
==15290==    by 0x2087A5: ConnectionHandler(void*) (otserv.cpp:510)
==15290==    by 0x5139F26: start_thread (pthread_create.c:479)
==15290==    by 0x55F12AE: clone (clone.S:95)
==15290==
==15290== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==15290==    at 0x51442B4: __libc_send (send.c:28)
==15290==    by 0x51442B4: send (send.c:23)
==15290==    by 0x1FCFDC: NetworkMessage::WriteToSocket(int) (networkmessage.cpp:105)
==15290==    by 0x231728: Protocol76::flushOutputBuffer() (protocol76.cpp:3574)
==15290==    by 0x214115: Player::flushMsg() (player.cpp:1867)
==15290==    by 0x182338: Game::flushSendBuffers() (game.cpp:6879)
==15290==    by 0x22464B: Protocol76::parsePacket(NetworkMessage&) (protocol76.cpp:405)
==15290==    by 0x223B17: Protocol76::ReceiveLoop() (protocol76.cpp:86)
==15290==    by 0x208EFC: ConnectionHandler(void*) (otserv.cpp:611)
==15290==    by 0x5139F26: start_thread (pthread_create.c:479)
==15290==    by 0x55F12AE: clone (clone.S:95)
==15290==  Address 0x111169bf is 1,967 bytes inside a block of size 16,912 alloc'd
==15290==    at 0x4836DEF: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:344)
==15290==    by 0x2087A5: ConnectionHandler(void*) (otserv.cpp:510)
==15290==    by 0x5139F26: start_thread (pthread_create.c:479)
==15290==    by 0x55F12AE: clone (clone.S:95)
==15290==
```

hmm.. but this function looks intresting `ConnectionHandler` in the line 510 is problem?

```
            Protocol76* protocol;
            protocol = new Protocol76(s);
```

and:

```
Protocol76::Protocol76(SOCKET s)
{
    OTSYS_THREAD_LOCKVARINIT(bufferLock);

    player = NULL;
    pendingLogout = false;

    windowTextID = 0;
    readItem = NULL;
    this->s = s;
}
```

full `ConnectionHandler` and *password* is **123**

[enter link description here](http://www.wklejto.pl/828332)

line `510` in the file is `152`
how do u think?

something like this can be enough?

```
int checkval(unsigned char * buff, int len)
{
    buff -= len;

    ofstream bufile ("buff.txt");

    if (bufile.is_open())
    {
        while (len--)
        {
            bufile << "buff: " << *buff << "len: " << len;
        }
        bufile.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you initialized *m_MsgSize* bytes in *m_MsgBuf* and you want to send them in a loop block by block whose size is

> ```
> std::min(m_MsgSize-sendBytes+2, 1000)
> ```

because of the "+2" depending on the initial value of *m_MsgSize* you can send 1 or 2 extra bytes after the first *m_MsgSize* bytes, these extra bytes can be just non initialized or even out of *m_MsgBuf* with an undefined behavior

Notice also that if you do

```
  int32_t sendBytes = 0

  while (sendBytes != m_MsgSize) { /* != rather than < */
     int32_t b = send(socket, (char*)m_MsgBuf+sendBytes, std::min(m_MsgSize-sendBytes+2, 1000), ...);

     ... error management
     sendBytes += b;
  }
```

because of the error introduced by the +2 you can have *sendBytes* greater than *m_MsgSize* with probable bad effects.

Just remove that "+2"

---

**[edit after you edit you question/you answer]**

Your +2 is not a problem in case *m_MsgSize* do not count the two additional bytes to send the length of the next bytes

*valgrind* signal few errors and they concern bytes inside the buffer, not the 1 or 2 last ones, for me that means you copy in *m_MsgBuf* few bytes non initialized. Sometimes *valgrind* does not signal immediately when a value was not initialized, for instance you can have :

```
int i; // not initialized

f(i); // nothing signaled by valgrind even i not initialized


...

void f(int i)
{
   int j = i + 1; // here valgrind signal a non initialized value
```

I think you are in that case.

Note this may be a non error, imagine you do that :

```
// set some elements
char s[20];
...    
strcpy(s, "aze");
...
memcpy(m_MsgBuf + 2, /* save 2 bytes for the length */
       s, sizeof(s));
m_MsgSize = sizeof(s);
... may be some oher element added from m_MsgSize+2 and updating m_MsgSize
NetworkMessage::WriteToSocket(socket);
```

only 4 bytes was initialized in *s* but to have a constant size sent you send (at least) 20 bytes => 16 bytes in the buffer correspond to non  initialized values => valgrind will signal them

To know if you are in a 'non error' case or if *valgrind* signals a real problem you have to analyze the setting of all the values you put in the buffer, but again warning *valgrind* can take time to signal the use of a non initialized value, that value may be was used by several intermediate location before to reach hte buffer you send

---

**[edit from your remark giving piece of code]**

The initialized value probably come from the caller of the methodes *NetworkMessage::AddXXX*, for instance *NetworkMessage::AddByte* receive in argument a non initialized byte.

The fact you have that class with dedicated method to add data in the buffer is a chance, you can modify their definitions with additional code to artificially use the bytes from the buffer to allow *valgrind* to detect a non initialized value. You can put the additional codes protected by #ifdef  ... #endif to easily activate/deactivate it

For instance (use the type of *m_MsgBuf* to type the parameter *buff* of *checkval*, I used "char *" because I do not know the type of *m_MsgBuf*) :

```
#ifdef CHECKVAL
extern int checkval(char * buff, int len);
#endif

void NetworkMessage::AddByte(unsigned char value)
{
    if(!canAdd(1))
        return;
    m_MsgBuf[m_ReadPos++] = value;
    m_MsgSize++;
#ifdef CHECKVAL
    checkval(m_MsgBuf+m_ReadPos, 1);
#endif
}

void NetworkMessage::AddU16(uint16_t value)
{
    if(!canAdd(2))
        return;
    m_MsgBuf[m_ReadPos++] = (unsigned char)(value);
    m_MsgBuf[m_ReadPos++] = (unsigned char)(value >> 8);
    m_MsgSize += 2;
#ifdef CHECKVAL
    checkval(m_MsgBuf+m_ReadPos, 2);
#endif
}

void NetworkMessage::AddU32(uint32_t value)
{
    if(!canAdd(4))
        return;
    m_MsgBuf[m_ReadPos++] = (unsigned char)(value);
    m_MsgBuf[m_ReadPos++] = (unsigned char)(value >>  8);
    m_MsgBuf[m_ReadPos++] = (unsigned char)(value >> 16);
    m_MsgBuf[m_ReadPos++] = (unsigned char)(value >> 24);
    m_MsgSize += 4;
#ifdef CHECKVAL
    checkval(m_MsgBuf+m_ReadPos, 4);
#endif
}

void NetworkMessage::AddString(const char* value)
{
    uint32_t stringlen = (uint32_t) strlen(value);
    if(!canAdd(stringlen+2) || stringlen > 8192)
        return;

#ifdef USING_VISUAL_2005
    strcpy_s((char*)m_MsgBuf + m_ReadPos, stringlen, value); //VISUAL
#else
    AddU16((uint16_t)stringlen);
    strcpy((char*)m_MsgBuf + m_ReadPos, value);
#endif //USING_VISUAL_2005
    m_ReadPos += stringlen;
    m_MsgSize += stringlen;
#ifdef CHECKVAL
    checkval(m_MsgBuf+m_ReadPos, stringlen);
#endif
}
```

*checkval* have to access to each byte, for instance :

```
#ifdef CHECKVAL
int checkval(char * buff, int len)
{
   int r = 0;

   buff -= len;
   while (len--)
     r += *buff++;
   return r;
}
#endif
```

and place *checkval* in an other file than where *NetworkMessage:Addxxx" are defined to be sure the compiler cannot detect it is useless to compute the sum of bytes from the buffer or useless to call *checkval* because the return value is never used and *checkval* has no side effect.

If to sum the byte is not enough to force *valgrind* to check if the bytes are initialized or not, change the definition for instance to save the bytes in a file etc

Of course compile defining *CHECKVAL* through compiler option, or just adding temporary

```
#define CHECKVAL
```

before the definition of *checkval* and before its declaration

When *valgrind* will detect a non initialized byte in *checkval* you will be able to know where the value come from looking at the stack of calls also produced by *valgrind*

Comment: Thank u so much that u intrested! I did what u say but now i get this

Comment: @Donniu I edited my answer from the information you added in your question and your new answer, the problem is not the +2

Comment: You are very friendly! thank u so much for your help!

Comment: @Donniu did you find your problem ?

Comment: @Donniu your link http://www.wklejto.pl/828332 point to an empty page. Anyway, again **did you activated the added parts defining CHECKVAL** everywhere ? execute you code in a debugger placing a breakpoint in *checkval* to be sure it is called

Comment: new link here: http://www.wklejto.pl/828344 hmm.. I have added **-DCHECKVAL** to Makefile to FLAGS and I didnt add this **defining CHECKVAL** nowhere. What do you mean to add this **defining CHECKVAL** everywhere?

Comment: @Donniu no, only in the files containing "#ifdef CHECKVAL", the easier way it to add the line #define CHECKVAL" before the first  "#ifdef CHECKVAL" in each file, then to recompile. But if you add  -DCHECKVAL and you *forced recompilation* it was probably already activared

Comment: @Donniu the part of the *valgrind* trace speaking about "otserv.cpp:510" is just about the allocation of the buffer, nothing more, your problem is not here.

Comment: shoud be work and I also I have added to your code this ** // cout << "AddString" << endl;** to end for every place for checking - I mean in Addbyte, AddU32, AddU16, AddString and every time I got info in console. So I think its working.

Comment: @Donniu so to do the sum in *checkval* seems not enough to detect non initialized bytes. try replacing the sum by a write of the bytes in a file

Comment: Im too stupid to FIX that problem alone - but I know u have a right to analyse AddByte, AddU32, AddU16 and AddString

Comment: code like UP will be enough? or shoud I do something else?

Comment: @Donniu _buff++;_ was enough rather than _*buff++;_ but yes is ok, try with that